# How To Remove Div and Img Tags From Document.Write in XHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

What I am trying to do is show a full screen background image on screens that are large enough and it works on most browsers but it is causing problems on others. I ran it through the W3 Validator and it says that XHTML doesn't support Div and Img tags in document.write. How else would I code this without document.write so that it would pass the validator and not cause errors on some browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullscreenBackground.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#background-image").fullscreenBackground();
    });
</script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
if (viewPortHeight >= 300 && viewPortWidth >= 400) {
document.write("<div id='background-image'><img src='BGLarge.gif' alt='background' width='1920' height='1080' ></div>");
}
else {
document.write("");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does fullscreenBackground() do?

Comment: Consider using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: It calls code from jquery.fullscreenBackground.js

Comment: Where are those script tags on your HTML? If they're in the head, that's probably what the validator is complaining about (you can't have div and img there). You should use prepend as the answers suggest, and do that from your document.ready handler, *before* you init the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (viewPortHeight >= 300 && viewPortWidth >= 400) {
  $('body').prepend('<div id="background-image"><img src="http://thetylerpress.com/new/BGLarge.gif" alt="background" width="1920" height="1080" ></div>');
}
```

You wont be needing the else statement

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing I had to change was 'body' to 'html' and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery to prepend your elements: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/.

This should work. Or you could just change your doctype.

Answer (score 1):

It would be usefull to know which browser raise errors. Anyway, why not using jQuery to achieve what you want ?

```
$('body').prepend(
    $('<div></div>')
        .attr('id', 'background-image')
        .html("<img src='http://thetylerpress.com/new/BGLarge.gif' alt='background' width='1920' height='1080' >")
);​
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wyd43/